# How to code logo and company name in header

Tags: html, css

How to code logo and company name in header

The following HTML file contains just a header at the top (a horizontal shim). https://jsfiddle.net/SSteven/yeamz57o/

```css
body {
  /* override browser defaults */
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.center {
  padding: 10px;
  /* vertical centering of <h1> */
  text-align: center;
  /* horizontal centering of <h1> */
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Make the logo and <h1> overlap */
}
```

```html
<!-- 
     The logo is given a height of 100px.
            Hence, the padding in the .center class
     must be set (by trial and error) to 10 px,
            to center-align 
    -->
<div class="clearfix center">
  <img class="logo" src="Logo_MarksC.png" alt="Logo" width="278" height="100">

  <h1>MY COMPANY</h1>
</div>
```

The header contains:
1) The Company logo at the left.
2) The Company name horizontally and vertically centered in the shim.

The following problems exist:
1) I have not been able to vertically center the logo perfectly in the shim.
   Right now, i have had to adjust the padding manually.
   What code can I use for perfect vertical centering of the logo?

2) Right now, I have made the logo and the Company name overlap, by using z-index. As a result, the Company name is horizontally centered perfectly in the full width of the web page. However, the problem is when the screen size is reduced horizontally, the Company name shifts left-ward and eventually slides behind the logo.

If I eliminate the overlap, the Company name will not be horizontally centered perfectly in the full width of the web page, but it solves the problem of the name sliding behind the logo when the screen width is reduced.

I'd like to ask in this connection:
If the header should accommodate a logo to the left and the Company name be horizontally centered, what is the normal / best practice?

Comment: Please use placeholder to add an image to the snippet I made

Comment: Use flex-box to vertical center. 
For overlapping, I would use a negative margin-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid absolute positioning. Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align the content.

You can create a spacer element to keep the two sides balanced so the heading ends up in the centre.

You should use an `@media` rule for narrow displays so that the layout changes. A squished heading is almost as bad as an overlapping one. (Note that in this example, due to the small frame Stackoverflow renders the page in, you'll probably have to hit the Full Screen link to avoid the media query switching to the vertical layout for narrow windows)

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  display: none
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
  }
  .logo,
  .spacer {
    display: block;
    width: 278px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
  .heading {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/278/100" alt="">
    <!-- alt is blank because the information conveyed in the image is duplicated by the heading -->
  </div>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Kitten Co</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    <!-- This exists just to use up space and so the heading is centred -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What can I say? Your solution is PERFECT. Thanks indeed for this code. The MQ was great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css flexbox for perfect centering. It's supported by all major browsers (IE may need a slight workaround), is a CSS standard now and removes all the annoying parts about aligning elements.

```
.my_class {
    display: flex;
}
.my_class--elements {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```